# CSS is not working in the server but its working well in the local machine

Tags: css, web-hosting

I am trying to upload a static website in the server and uploaded it successfully but only HTML is showing, CSS  is not showing. but when I run it on my local computer it's working perfectly.
king

Comment: question duplicate has been removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to change the link of **Style.css** and **media.css** because it's a local link.

Imagine your files are stored in Resources folder, then you should change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/Style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/media.css">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Resources/css/Style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Resources/css/media.css">
```

and there is a same problem with your scripts.js link. look at this line:

```
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
```

and it should be similarly changed to this:

```
<script src="/resources/js/script.js"></script>
```

It refers to a local directory too.

Answer (score 2):

The link to your stylesheet in the `head` is wrong/doesn't work (file not found):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/Style.css">
```

Apparently that's a local link, but you need to adapt it to the server/domain environment

Comment: sorry but actually I have no idea what is an adaption to the server or domain environment.i will be very grateful if you describe or show me how to achieve that

Comment: You need to put the correct filepath in that piece of code I posted - where your stylesheet is actually situated on your webspace, either its complete URL including the domain or a correct relative path to the css file.

Comment: what would be the correct file path?

Comment: That's up to you to find out – only *you* know where you put your CSS file on the server... (And if you don't, just look into all directories to find out)

Answer (score 1):

The name of your css file is `style.css` but it is linked as `Style.css`.