# CSS showing locally but not on dockerized server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, docker

I've been working on a web page with HTML and CSS using a template that I found online, and when I look at it locally everything is fine, but when I look at it mounted on the server CSS does not show.
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1AbA.jpg)

[When it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Xpe.jpg)

I tried to correct source of the css like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940061/css-is-not-working-in-the-server-but-its-working-well-in-the-local-machine)

This is how my HTML INdex looks like

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400">
    <!-- Google web font "Open Sans" -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="/text/css" href="/slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="/text/css" href="/slick/slick-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tooplate-style.css">
```

and this is how I am using the JS

```
    <!-- load JS files -->
    <script type="/text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- https://popper.js.org/ -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- https://getbootstrap.com/ -->
    <script type="/text/javascript" src="/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Slick Carousel -->
```

For some reason, it does work when i'm doing the editing locally, but once mounted on the server it does not show up correctly

edit:
This is how I'm handling the node app.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const log4js = require('log4js');

const logger = log4js.getLogger();
logger.level = 'debug';

  //http =>
  //cliente =>(request, response) servidor
http.createServer((request, response)=>{

  if(request.url){
    const file = request.url == '/' ? './WWW/index.html' : `./WWW${request.url}`;
    fs.readFile(file, (err, data)=> {

      if (err){
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        logger.warn(`NOT FOUND ${request.method} ${request.url}`);
        response.write("NOT FOUND");
      }else{
        logger.info(`OK ${request.method} ${request.url}`)
        // Encabezado de la respuesta http
        // parametro 1) Estatus del protocolo http
        // 2) Tipo de contenido (Content Type) => text/html text/plain text/json
        if (file.split('.').pop() == 'png') {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
        }else if (file.split('.').pop() == 'jpg') {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/jpg"});
        }else if (file.split('.').pop() == 'pdf') {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/pdf"});
        }else {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
        }
        // Contenido del cuerpo de la respuesta

        response.write(data);
      }
      response.end();

    });
  }
}).listen(4000);
```

Edit 2: solved
Ok. The problem was in the node app.js
I nedeed to add an if for it to recognize css like this:

```
        if (file.split('.').pop() == 'png') {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
        }else if (file.split('.').pop() == 'jpg') {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/jpg"});
        }else if (file.split('.').pop() == 'pdf') {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/pdf"});
          
        }
        
        else if (file.split('.').pop() == 'css') {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css;"});
          
        }
        
        else {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
        }
```

Now it works as it should

Comment: What's the console saying?

Comment: It's saying that Slider slick is not a function, that's all the erros it's showing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

> /slick/slick.min.js

use  this

> ./slick/slick.min.js

as url and slick should be in the root directory

Comment: It didn't solved the problem but it actually helped me see what I was doing wrong, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The problem was in the node app.js I nedeed to add an if for it to recognize css like this:

```
    if (file.split('.').pop() == 'png') {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
    }else if (file.split('.').pop() == 'jpg') {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/jpg"});
    }else if (file.split('.').pop() == 'pdf') {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/pdf"});
      
    }
    
    else if (file.split('.').pop() == 'css') {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css;"});
      
    }
    
    else {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
    }
```

Now it works as it should